# Jquery scrollTop not working as it should in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, scrolltop

I am building a onepage website which uses the `scrollTop()` function from Jquery.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 140;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': targetOffset
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

It works fine on Chrome, Safari en Vivaldi, but when I run the website in FireFox, it doesn't take take my targetOffset.
Is there a way to fix this, while not affecting the other browsers?

a preview of the site can be found on http://listycon.kiran.be

**EDIT** I did a screencapture to clarify the problem, you can see it on this link: http://kiranvanursel.tinytake.com/sf/MTYxMTg5XzEwMTM1Njk

Comment: Can you share your HTML code ??

Comment: That site works on mine. I use firefox

Comment: dispite my answer, it works for me as well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like firefox has some trouble to grab the .hash from the href in your a-tag.
You could try something along these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        href = '#' + href.split('#').pop();

        var $target = $(href).offset().top - 140;

        $('html, body').animate({
            'scrollTop': $target
        }, 900, 'swing', function () { 
            window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", href);
        });
    });
});
```

Cropping the hash from the href attribute should work in every browser.

---

maybe the 'jump' results from setting the `window.location.hash`.

Try to update the url using an [html5 pushstate](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/) event. I have updated the code block, i think its worth the try

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately the problem is still there. 

the browsers scrolls to the right position, and then jumps the amount of offset to the top